# While loop and GUI

Tags: java, swing, jcombobox, jtextarea

The following code only shows my one answer i.e. 1 element in TextArea and not all, I want it to be a list.

```
double s = Double.parseDouble(amount.getText());    
double p = Double.parseDouble(interest.getText()) / 100;    
double t = Double.parseDouble(period.getText());    
double m=t*12;    
int x=1;    
double lin = s * Math.pow(1+ p, x);    
double anu =s+(s*p*t);

while(x<=m && JComboBox.getSelectedItem().equals("Anuitetas")) {    
      JTextArea.setText(String.valueOf(anu));    
      x++;
}

while(x<=m && JComboBox.getSelectedItem().equals("Linijinis")){    
     JTextArea.setText(String.valueOf(lin));    
     x++;
}
```

Comment: Well you're repeatedly calling `setText`, which *will* replace the contents. If you want a *list*, perhaps you should be looking for a component which is designed to display a list? You should also put more effort into your question - format the code properly, and remove everything irrelevant from it. See http://tinyurl.com/so-hints

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`JList` would display all your items instead of a `JTextbox` which is replacing items instead of appending it. This is just a example of how you can work it out.

```
DefaultListModel listModel = new DefaultListModel();
JList list = new JList(listModel);

while(x<=m && JComboBox.getSelectedItem().equals("Linijinis")){

     addNewElement(String.valueOf(lin));
     x++;
}

public static void addNewElement(String elementToAdd)
{
    listModel.addElement(elementToAdd);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Don't use `JTextArea#setText`, use `JTextArea#append` instead

You should also consider using a [`JList`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/list.html) instead, which is designed to do just that, list items...